# The pagination buttons are misaligned in chat search

Tags: bug, chat, design, google-chrome, chat-search

When searching in chat, the first button in the pagination links at the bottom is elevated higher than the rest of the buttons:

> [image: When on Page 1]
>   [image: When on Any Page Other than 1]

Comment: Is this Chrome stable? I've had this issue a while in dev, but when I last checked in Chrome stable/other browsers I couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @TimStone: Yes, the latest stable release.

Comment: I can reproduce it on Google Chrome 25.0.1364.152 running on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: That's annoying. The fun part is, if you disable and then reenable the float on those elements, they suddenly align correctly.

Comment: grrrrr; that's just vexing (edit: I mean: vexing that this would suddenly happen out of the blue, rather than vexing that you would report it)

Comment: I actually *like* it that way...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what changed in Chrome to cause this, but I think the right-floated RSS feed link + the pager's `clear: both` is to blame for the offset, due to some calculation issue during the initial render.

The following set of changes fixes the problem in Chrome, without disturbing anything in Firefox (as far as I can tell, and I was too lazy to try and recreate my changes in IE):

1. Move feed `<a>` before `.pager`
2. Remove `.clear-both` from `.pager`
3. Remove `margin-top: 20px` from `.pager`
4. Add `margin-top: 10px` (or thereabouts) to feed `<a>`

Gives you:

[image: mocked up fix]

Looks like this scenario is currently being [tracked as a Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178137), which I'll baselessly speculate might be related to [this WebKit changeset](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/136967/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderBlockLineLayout.cpp).